# How to split csv files into multiple files using the delimiter? python

Tags: python, unix, csv, cut

I have a tab delimited file as such:

this is a sentence. abb
what is this foo bar.   bev
hello foo bar blah black sheep. abb

I could use `cut -f1` and `cut -f2` in unix terminal to split into two files:

```
this is a sentence.
what is this foo bar.
hello foo bar blah black sheep.
```

and:

```
abb
bev
abb
```

**But is it possible to do the same in python? would it be faster?**

I've been doing it as such:

```
[i.split('\t')[0] for i in open('in.txt', 'r')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *But is it possible to do the same in python?*

yes you can:

```
l1, l2 = [[],[]]

with open('in.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i in f:
        # will loudly fail if more than two columns on a line
        left, right = i.split('\t')
        l1.append(left)
        l2.append(right)

print("\n".join(l1))
print("\n".join(l2))
```

> *would it be faster?*

it's not likely, *cut* is a C program that is optimized towards that kind of processing, python is a general purpose language which has a great flexibility, but is not necessarily fast.

Though, the only advantage you may get by working with an algorithm such as the one I wrote, is that you read the file only once, whereas with cut, you're reading it twice. That could make the difference.

Though we'd need to run some benchmarking to be 100%.

Here's a small benchmark, on my laptop, for what it's worth:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=lambda: t("file_of_606251_lines"), number=1)
1.393364901014138
```

vs

```
% time cut -d' ' -f1 file_of_606251_lines > /dev/null
cut -d' ' -f1 file_of_606251_lines > /dev/null  0.74s user 0.02s system 98% cpu 0.775 total
% time cut -d' ' -f2 file_of_606251_lines > /dev/null
cut -d' ' -f2 file_of_606251_lines > /dev/null  1.18s user 0.02s system 99% cpu 1.215 total
```

which is 1.990 seconds.

So the python version is indeed faster, as expected ;-)